# C++ FFmpeg how to continue encoding after flushing?

Tags: c++, qt, ffmpeg, h.264

I write the received packets in binary files. When the recording of the first file is completed, I call flush:

`avcodec_send_frame(context, NULL);`

This is the signal to end the stream. But when I send a new frame to the encoder, function return **AVERROR_EOF** *(man: the encoder has been flushed, and no new frames can be sent to it)*. What to do to make the encoder take the frames after flushing?

**Example:** when decoding, you can call:

`avcodec_flush_buffers(context);`

This function changes the stream, but only for decoding.
Maybe analogic function for encoding?

**Ideas:**

1) do not call flush. But the encoder buffers frames inside and gives some packets only after flushing *(using h.264 with b-frames)*, while some packets get into the next file.

2) Recreate codec context?

**Details:** *use Win 7, Qt 5.10, ffmpeg 4.0.2*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer is that you should create a new codec context for each file, or headache will follow. The little expense of additional headers and key frames should be small unless you are doing something very exotic.

B-frames can refer to both previous and future frames, how would you even decide such a beast?

In theory you could probably force a keyframe and hope for the best, but then there is really no point in not starting a new context, unless the hundreds of bytes or so of H264 init data is a problem.

Comment: Thanks, Krumelur! We'll have to create a new context. I just hoped that there was some function that would reset the context with issuing the remaining packets in the encoder.

Comment: If you finish the stream, you have no remaining packets. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: For encoding it is the same as for decoding: `avcodec_flush_buffers(context);`. Afterwards you can start sending data again without any hassle.

Comment: @nice_pink I think that might be incorrect. I get the message " Ignoring attempt to flush encoder that doesn't support it" and frames from consecutive file writes seem to be overlapping.